# Azure App Service web authentication guidance

Tags: web-services, cordova, azure

I'm trying to get Google authentication working against Azure App Service from a web site and later hopefully from Cordova. There is a lot of information related to the old Azure Mobile Services, but not much on App Services. Microsoft did exclude tutorials on how to do it from web.

I included `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js"></script>`, don't know if this is still current?

Any pointers on how to handle authentication are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the Authentication/Authorization feature. Refer this article for more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication/

AFAIK, there is no native support for Cordova in Azure App Service Mobile App. You will have to implement this yourself.